# Symfony get all users on a specific page

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to find a way to get all users browsing on the same page.

I already know how to get all logged users on my website but I'm trying to get all logged users browsing on a specific page.
I don't know if this is possible and how, if it is possible.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you tell specific page you deal with specific controller.
In this specific controller which render specific template webPage you can valid if the user is authentified.

If authentified you can launch a listener (and only launch this listener in this controller) which create a specific log (or database insert) on user/authentified trig this trigger.

You can also filter users which launch trigger before run the code and categorize your log.

Otherwise (but not very good) is to create a kernel listener which launch anytime and for each user and request you can decide to (according to many others arguments) throw specific action and logger. With this you can create a best engine for log very specific behaviour on your website for each user.

Perhaps you can find if bundle already exist for this...Or detail using of Monolog component of Symfony framework